# How to decode the JSON array into two variable?

Tags: javascript

In the given function I'm passing the data which is in a json format like this

```
[{"Date":"2014-12-12 18:52:10","TTC":"0"},{"Date":"2014-12-12 18:52:10","TTC":"0"},{"Date":"2014-12-12 18:53:10","TTC":"0"},{"Date":"2014-12-12 18:53:10","TTC":"0"},{"Date":"2014-12-12 19:02:11","TTC":"0"}]
```

The JSON array is too long and I want to store the Date into date array and TTC into ttc please help to parse this.

```
 function drawChart(data){

        console.log(data);
        var date = [];
        var ttc = [];

        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){

            date.push(data[i]['Date']);
            console.log(date);
            ttc.push(parseInt(data[i]["TTC"]));
            //console.log(ttc);
        }
}
```

Comment: i see no reason to tag it with php ... you have javascript function

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```js
var data = [{
  "Date": "2014-12-12 18:52:10",
  "TTC": "0"
}, {
  "Date": "2014-12-12 18:52:10",
  "TTC": "0"
}, {
  "Date": "2014-12-12 18:53:10",
  "TTC": "0"
}, {
  "Date": "2014-12-12 18:53:10",
  "TTC": "0"
}, {
  "Date": "2014-12-12 19:02:11",
  "TTC": "0"
}];

function drawChart(data) {
  var date = [];
  var ttc = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    date.push(data[i]['Date']);
    ttc.push(parseInt(data[i]["TTC"]));
  }
  return {
    date: date,
    ttc: ttc
  };
}
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(drawChart(data));
```

> you need to return an object which will contain your arrays

Comment: Op has provided his `js` function. Difficult to make out that he is looking for `php` solution..

Comment: its really wtf by op ... sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

In order to access it like an object you have to parse it like this:

```
obj = JSON.parse(data);
```